# can I change this html tag/code with javascript/jquery with a submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched online for changing html code with javascript but all I kept on finding is something like .innerHTML and then output text.
I'm wondering if we can change the html code in the back end with just javascript/jquery/json

e.g I have an input text area with an output text that's red with `.class1` and a submit button then in the text area I type in class2 or 2 then the `.class1` changes to `.class2` after submitting.

just an example with some simple codes here.

```
//so I have two classes here just for example
.class1
{
    color:red;
}

.class2
{
    color:blue;
}

//form with action and method and a text area input and a submit button
<form action=" " method="post">
<label>Which class</label><input type="text">
<input type="submit">

//let's say this is the original out put (.class1 with text Using Class 1 in blue)
<p class="class1"> Using Class 1</p>
```

so now let's say in the text area I typed in class2 then click submit

`<p class="class1"> Using Class 1</p>`
changes to
        `<p class="class2"> Using Class 2</p>`

or even if there's no class3 but if in the text area I input class3 or gibberish and the output would be something like     `<p class="class3 or gibberish"> Using class3 or gibberish</p>`

I'm actually more interested in how changing this `<p class="class3 or gibberish">` can be done more than the `Using class 3` part.

Hopefully my explanation isn't too gibberish.

Thanks in advance people~

Comment: Do you want to actually post the form or do the class change client side only?

Comment: When you say "_I'm wondering if we can change the html code in the back end with just javascript/jquery/json_" you meant "front end"? Remember that js/jquery are interpreted in the client side (front), not server side (end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done using Jquery.Following solution will help to achieve your need.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .class1
        {
            color:red;
        }

        .class2
        {
            color:green;
        }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnSubmit() {
        $("#p1").replaceWith("<p class='" + $("#txtInput").val() + "' id ='p1' >using" + $("#txtInput").val() + " </p>");
        return false;
    }    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=" " id="frm">
    <label>
        Which class</label><input type="text" id="txtInput">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick=" return fnSubmit();">
    <p class="class1" id="p1">
        Using Class 1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: weird I edited my codes into your post few hours ago but it's gone now

Comment: I found a post pretty similar to what I want and I read the post his problem isn't solved yet interested in reading that post?

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, you need to use `removeAttr('class')` to get rid of any existing styles, then `addClass()` to put the new one on. Try this:

```
<label>Which class</label>
<input type="text" id="class-name" />
<input type="button" id="update" value="Update" />
<p class="class1">Using Class 1</p>
```

```js
$('#update').click(function () {
    var newClass = $('#class-name').val();
    $('p')
        .removeAttr('class')
        .addClass(newClass)
        .text('Using ' + newClass);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4k3xy/1)

Comment: the question does say *after submitting*?

Comment: @Liam well that would be impossible as the page would have been refreshed, so the state of the JS would be reset.

Comment: @Liam no problem, sorry if it came across harsh.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You can block the default submit behaviour and its refresh by using `.preventDefault()`

Comment: @smonti then why bother with the `form` at all?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I wouldn't use a form for this purpose either... And why not using the `.prop()` function? Would save us the `removeClass()`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @smonti it would indeed. `removeAttr()` came to mind first, although you're correct `removeProp` is better practice in this case.

Comment: Don't worry @RoryMcCrossan, I've had worse ;P. All good points above.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Try this

```
$('#update').click(function () {
    $('p').removeclass('old class name').addClass('new class-name')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. You can `removeClass()` and then `addClass()` the class you need and then change the text you want to display
2. You can surround `<p>` with a `<div>` and over-write `<p>` all together using `innerHTML` of the `<div>`.